# Checkboxes with anchors

Tags: javascript, html

I have a ton of check-box's that are linked to anchors. When a check-box is clicked it goes to that anchor which is in the same page. Is there a better way to code this? I have about 50 check-box's so this function is packed with if statements.This is the working code for 2 of them:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" onclick="return send();"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" onclick="return send();"/>

<script>
function send(){
    if(document.getElementById('1').checked){
        window.location='#buy';
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('2').checked){
        window.location='#order';
        return false;
    }

//and this function goes on and on and on...
        return true;

    }
    </script>
```

And then in the page where I want it to go has

```
<a name="buy"></a>
<a name="order"></a>
```

Comment: Just a remark: in valid HTML ids of DOM elements cannot start with a number.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - in HTML5 it can.

Comment: According to the W3C, http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#the-id-attribute  the only restriction is there is no space in it.

Comment: @j08691, sure, except that HTML5 is still a draft. I was talking about current standards.

Comment: You might consider using radio buttons over checkboxes . . . otherwise, you could potentially have two boxes checked at the same time, which could mess up the logic.  Also avoids the "unchecked" scenerio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the hash into the value of the input like so:

`<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="buy" onclick="return send(this);"/>`

You could do it like so

```
<script>
function send(input)
{
    if(input.checked)
    {
        window.location = input.value;
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
```

If that doesn't work you could also switch out the value to use `ID` or even a custom attribute. Whatever suits your fancy.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will save your nerves here:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
  windows.location = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Simply make sure you change the anchors to match the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" data-target="buy" onclick=" send(this)">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="2" data-target="order" onclick="send(this)">
```

Javscript:

```
function send(el){
  var target = '#' + el.getAttribute('data-target');
  window.location = target ;
}
```